# The set of compatible vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, submanifold

Let us fix some smooth vector field $F(x)$ in some open submanifold $M\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, $n\ge3$. A vector field $G(x)$ is said to be compatible with $F(x)$ if the Lie bracket $[F,G]$ is a linear combination of $F(x)$ and $G(x)$, i.e.
$$
\forall x\in M \quad [F(x),G(x)]= \alpha(x) F(x)+\beta(x) G(x),
$$
where $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ are some smooth scalar functions.

Denote by $C_F$ the set of all smooth vector fields compatible with a given vector field $F(x)$. What is the structure of the set $C_F$? Does it always contain any vector fields other than fields of the form $\gamma(x) F(x)$,
where $\gamma(x)$ is a smooth scalar function? And if so, how can one get such vector fields?

Comment: The condition at a generic point (where $F$ and $G$ are linearly independent) is equivalent to $$F \wedge G \wedge [F, G] = 0,$$ which is a system of ${\dim M} \choose 3$ first-order, quadratic differential equations in the components of $G$. At each point this equation determines a quadratic condition on the space of $1$-jets of the component functions of $g$. Locally, there is an infinite-dimensional family of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The vector fields $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ determine an [integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29#Formulation_using_vector_fields) distribution. So you would look for $2$-dimensional foliations of $M$ whose leaves contain the trajectories of $F$. That can be done in many ways...

Note: if $G(x)$ is such a vector field, and $\phi$ is a smooth function then $\phi \cdot G$ is again.

I am not sure that it is a vector space ( closed under addition). Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I confused with the case $[F,G]=0$. I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: @AVK: No worries :-) And it is a neat question, gets into foliations

Comment: And yes, I know the Frobenius theorem. I don't know how to "turn it inside out" :)

Comment: @AVK: such vector fields $F$, $G$ ( assuming they are independent on some small open subset) are tangent to the leaves of a foliation ( family of submanifolds of dimension $2$. The leaves have to contain the trajectories of $F$. You can look at the intergral curves of $F$ an put them together to get those leaves.  Say every trajectory starts from a certain point of $S$ ( a codim $1$ section of $M$ transversal to $F$) Now, partition $S$ into curves, and those will be the starting points for the leaves.

Comment: @AVK: the point is this $F(x)$, $G(x)$ at each point generate a two dimensional vector space (assume they are not collinear) This  family $2$-dim subspaces has to be an intgrable distribution. So if we change from $G(x)$ to $\phi G(x) + \psi F(x)$ it's still OK. And they generate the same distribution.

Comment: "You can look at the intergral curves of F an put them together to get those leaves." - I don't see how this can be done in the general case. In terms of dynamical systems, this is the problem of finding the first integral (or its level surfaces). There are no general ways to find it, but the main thing is that its existence is guaranteed only locally in some neighborhood of a non-singular point and there are no guarantees that the first integral/foliation exists globally on M.

Comment: To make sure that this is not easy, it is enough to take any chaotic system. It is extremely doubtful that for them there exists such a global family of submanifolds of dimension 2. And if they do exist, it is completely incomprehensible how to combine the integral curves into 2-dimensional manifolds

Comment: @AVK: Indeed, there could be complications. Even $F$ can have complicated singularities. Perhaps the easier cases would shed some light.